# Server Side Processing at DataTable

Tags: php

I am using DataTable at server side processing. Here table shows no Datas in table

```
var DataTableApp = $('#DataTableApp').dataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "php/getAppDetails.php",
            "bRetrieve":true,
            "bDestroy":true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                var imei_apps = document.getElementById('imei').value;
                console.log(imei_apps);
                aoData.push( { "name": "imei", "value": imei_apps } );
            },

            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData": "appName",             
            }, {
                "mData": "appId",
            }, {
                "mData": "versionInstalled"
            }, {
                "mData": "appSize",
            }, {
                "mData":"dataSize",
            },{
                "mData": "appType",
            },{
                "mData":"installedLocation",
            },{
                "mData": "appType",
            }],
        });
```

What is the mistake in that code. I cant find the solutions

Comment: What does the code @ `php/getAppDetails.php` look like?

Comment: response is like {"aaData":{"appId":null,"appName":"Test2","versionInstalled":null,"appSize":null,"dataSize":null,"appType":null,"installedLocation":null,"installedTime":null},"isSuccessful":true}

Comment: aaData should be an array, not an object.

Comment: So how to retrive that in DataTable

Comment: The problem isn't in dataTables, it's your php that's returning incorrect JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your response similar to this:

```
{"sEcho": $sEcho, "iTotalRecords": $total, "iTotalDisplayRecords": $filtered,
 "aaData": [
     [$row1_col1, $row1_col2, $row1_col3],
     [$row2_col1, $row2_col2, $row2_col3]
  ]}
```

In PHP it would look like this:

```
$json = new stdClass;
$json->aaData = array();
$json->aaData[] = array($row1_col1, $row1_col2, $row1_col3);
$json->aaData[] = array($row2_col1, $row2_col2, $row2_col3);

$encoded_json = json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I am inserting values like aaData=array(...). from your reference. How to add [] this format

Comment: I udpated my answer with a way to build the desired output in php. It's an object with a property `aaData` that is an array of arrays.